# How to create string from webpage on android?

Tags: java, android, string

I am sorry I am very beginner in android / java.
I have searched what I'm looking for but I didn't find it.

My problem: 
I put admob ads in my application, sometimes I got trouble and I need to change admob id without update the apps.

What I'm looking for is I want to set admob id in MainActivity.java through my web page.

for example:

My web page that contains admob id eg.: ca-app-pub-243434xxxx/3434xx

```
http://mywebsite.com/android/admob_id.txt
```

I want to get that admob id and place it to "HERE_IS_ADMOB_ID" in MainActivity.java

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>
> InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
> Button mNewGameButton;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     mNewGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);
>
>     mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
>     mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("HERE_IS_ADMOB_ID"); // <=== ADMOB ID
>
>     mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onAdClosed() {
>             requestNewInterstitial();
>             beginPlayingGame();
>         }
>     });
>
>     requestNewInterstitial();
> ...
> ```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

> My web page that contains admob id eg.: ca-app-pub-243434xxxx/3434xx
>
> http://mywebsite.com/android/admob_id.txt
>
> and place it to "HERE_IS_ADMOB_ID" in MainActivity.javaI want to get that admob id

The Approach you should go is **to create one WebService which will provide you ADMOB-ID in response and provide the same to your relevant `Activity`**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you describe it more detail?